# Error response from daemon: Drive has not been shared

Tags: docker

In Windows 10, trying to mount an external volume in docker

`docker run --rm -v d:/data:/data alpine ls /data`

gives this error

`Error response from daemon: Drive has not been shared.`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ensure you have shared the drive in settings

[image]

```
PS c:\>docker --version
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed the problem for me

Comment: Are there any downside of sharing drives? Or why is this not default?

Comment: Just for completeness, in Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b this is located under Resources -> File Sharing, rather than under Shared Drives.